# Unity 2d с платформой под андроид крашиться при пакете urp

Tags: unity3d

Я новичок в разработке света в Unity, посмотрел туториалы и решил использовать пакет URP, при установке пакета сперва крашнулся проект, но потом перезашёл и текстуры стали какие-то странные(яркие цвета). В этом проекте изначально была платформа под Android без пакета URP.

Решил попробовать создать новый тестовый проект 2d с платформой под windows. Пакет URP работает отлично, пока я не ставлю платформу под Android. Unity сразу крашиться и невозможно зайти в проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]